# My question was deleted as I was editing it!

Tags: discussion

My [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/329763/can-the-use-of-a-greek-word-in-an-english-sentence-change-which-syllable-in-th) was deleted as I was editing it!

That's frustrating, was it automatic? Am I allowed to try and start another question to ask it?

Comment: Thanks for adding the link. As the banner explains, your question was deleted by the "Community" user, which is not a real user but a process that automatically deletes questions that meet certain criteria laid out in the following Help center page: https://english.stackexchange.com/help/roomba

Comment: @sumelic weird timing. don't be mad, i'm gonna see if i can rephrase it.

Comment: I assume something changed recently about your question that caused it to meet the criteria. It was only closed fairly recently, and maybe someone downvoted it after that. That would explain the timing. To answer the rest of your question, you are allowed to re-post the question, but it will be at risk of being closed again unless it addresses the issues that caused people to close the first one

Comment: thanks @sumelic will do my best

Answer (score 6):

Please see the help: https://english.stackexchange.com/help/roomba

There are several criteria for automatic deletion. Your question was removed for the reason "RemoveDeadQuestions":

> The Community user will automatically delete old abandoned/dead questions in the following circumstances:
>
> If the question is more than 30 days old, and ...
>
> - has −1 or lower score
> - has no answers
> - is not locked
>
> ... it will be automatically deleted. These are termed "dead" questions.

I guess that the question was downvoted today, perhaps as a result of being bumped through editing. Once that downvote was received, it would have been deleted whether or not it was closed.

The script which does it runs around midnight GMT, with other automatic cleanup things like the rogue voting reversal script.

You can ask it again, but please make sure it's on topic.

Comment: The question has been at -1 (+1/-2) since [June 21](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/329763/timeline). I think closure was the trigger.

Comment: If it was just deleted by the roomba, why not simply undelete it? IIRC, even the OP can self-undelete a roomba-deleted post.